# Twitter accounts I follow not appearing?

Tags: twitter

Some of the accounts I follow don't appear on my timeline. I have unfollowed and re-followed them. The users in question are sending tweets but I can't see them. Can you help?

Comment: Is it shows _Following_?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the reason to not see tweets from an user:

- You may be trying to follow accounts with *protected Tweets*. Users with protected Tweets will first need to approve your request to follow them.
- You may have hit a following limit.
- Twitter only allow you to follow a certain number of users per day and per account in order to limit spam.

In your case I guess first one is the problem.